# Python: Generated (Orco) Texture Coordinate to 2D Image

Tags: python, texturing, image, coordinates, procedural

**Summary**: How to sample/evaluate a procedural texture using *Generated* (orco) texture coordinates, such that the resulting image will affect the object identical to that of the procedural texture, when used for texturing (BI) and displace modifier using Generated and Local texture coordinates respectively.

**Long Version w/ Code:** I'm trying to save a procedural texture with Generated texture coordinates as 2D image. Such that when the image is used with Generated texture coordinates it gives the same exact result as the procedural texture.

Before continuing I need to clarify that I'm not interested in "baking" solutions or those involving UV mapping and looking for a python alternative that can properly map the Generated texco to image x,y grid. Also everything below is done in Blender Internal.

[image]

I have two objects with identical geometry. 
The first object on the right, object **RIGHT** is being displaced using a procedural texture with *Local* texture coordinate system. For the material texture I'm using the *Generated* mapping which perfectly corresponds to the *Local* texture of the displacement modifier.

The second object on the right, object **LEFT** is being modified by a displacement modifier using our saved image texture (from procedural), and similarly has a material texture with *Generated* coordinate system corresponding to *Local* coords of the modifier.

This image texture used for LEFT is the *sampled version* of the Procedural texture of the RIGHT.

I've been able to generate this image from the procedural texture using the [evaluate](https://docs.blender.org/api/249PythonDoc/Texture.Texture-class.html#evaluate) function from the API. The code generating the image is below:

```
import bpy
import numpy as np
D = bpy.data

image_object = D.images["Untitled"]
texture = D.textures["Wood"]
pixels = D.images["Untitled"].pixels
rows = D.images["Untitled"].generated_height
columns = D.images["Untitled"].generated_width

data = np.asarray( pixels, dtype="float" )

print("Texture Copy Started")
print(data.shape)
data3d = data.reshape(rows, columns, 4)

# Values below are arbitrary to get some reasonable results
# probably some formula to get proper results
scaleI = 70
scaleJ = 70

for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(columns):
        x, y = i/scaleI , j/scaleJ 
        # texture.evaluate takes in a coordinate. How to get the correct one?
        intensity = texture.evaluate((x,y,0)).w
        data3d[i,j][0] = intensity 
        data3d[i,j][1] = intensity 
        data3d[i,j][2] = intensity 

# Ensure (0,0) corresponds to bottom left and is blue
data3d[0,0][0] = 0
data3d[0,0][1] = 0
data3d[0,0][2] = 1

# Ensure (width/2, height/2) corresponds to middle and is green
y = int(rows/2)
x = int(columns/2)
data3d[x, y][0] = 0
data3d[x, y][1] = 1
data3d[x, y][2] = 0

# Ensure (255,255) corresponds to top right and is red
y = rows - 1
x = columns - 1
data3d[x, y][0] = 1
data3d[x, y][1] = 0
data3d[x, y][2] = 0

D.images["Untitled"].pixels = data3d.reshape(rows*columns*4)
print("Copy texture completed")
print(data3d.reshape(rows*columns*4))
```

Resulting in the following for a 256x256 image.

[image: generated image from the wood procedural texture using code above]

My main question is **how can I sample the procedural texture considering the texture coordinates of *Generated* (orco) such that when I use the image texture on LEFT I will get the same exact result as RIGHT, meaning they both look identical**.

I've read a lot about this, but the material is quite obscure. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809053/extracting-blender-original-coordinates-orco), I've read that `**Orco(v) = 2*(v-center)/size**` for v, vertex. But I'm not sure how to use this knowledge in computing the image.

[On the other](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?36482-Compute-UV-in-ORCO-mode) hand I've read that `**(minX, minY) --> (0,0)**` and `**(maxX, maxY) --> (1,1)**` for Generated coordinates, but I'm not sure how this correlates with the above formula for Orco(v)?

Before anything, I want to say that I greatly appreciate your help in advance.

Here are some resources that I've already looked at:

- [Image Pixels to Vertex Weight](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?269548-Image-Pixels-to-Vertex-Weight)
- [Blender Displace Modifier Source 1](https://github.com/dfelinto/blender/blob/master/source/blender/modifiers/intern/MOD_util.c)
- [Blender Displace Modifier Source 2](https://github.com/martijnberger/blender/blob/c359343f8dae6689c955dc1fa700cb26f6cd2e95/source/blender/modifiers/intern/MOD_displace.c)
- [Convert Procedural Texture to UV maps without rendering](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/260/is-there-a-way-to-convert-procedural-textures-to-uv-maps-without-rendering-a-fin)
- [Extracting Blender Original Coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809053/extracting-blender-original-coordinates-orco)
- [Displacement Modifier and Texture Coordinates](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45335/displacement-modifier-and-texture-coordinates)

Comment: @CoDEmanX would highly appreciate the help <3

Comment: same with @batFINGER :)

Comment: and of course @gandalf3

Comment: That is not how comment @replies work. None of those people got pinged See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/278094 for how the @ reply system works.